# Theoretical dependency of moments on parameter of a Boltzmann distribution

Tags: probability, distributions, moments

Assume
$$X\sim \frac{e^{-\beta Nf(x)}}{Z_{\beta}}$$
where 
$$
f(x) = -hx -x^2 + \frac{1}{\beta N}(1-x)\ln(1-x) + (1+x)\ln(1+x)
$$
and $Z_{\beta}$ is the appropriate normalization factor.
The support of $X$ is the lattice $\Gamma_N = \{-1,-1+2/N,\ldots,1-2/N,1\}$ and $N$ is some large positive integer and $\beta>1$.

I would like to know if there's any way to characterize the first three moments of $X$, that is

$$
\mathbb{E}[X],
\mathbb{E}[X^2],\mathbb{E}[X^3]$$

as functions of $\beta$ and whatever else comes out, but in particular I'm interested in the overall behaviour when $\beta$ grows large.

If you are familiar with statistical physics this is the Curie Weiss model (or a mean field Ising model).

Answer (score 1):

Since this model constitutes [an exponential family](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_family), the moments can be derived from the [moment generating function of the sufficient statistic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_family#Moment-generating_function_of_the_sufficient_statistic):
$$\Psi(u)=\mathbb E_\beta[e^{u f(X)}]=\int e^{u f(x)-\beta N f(x)-\log Z_\beta} \text{d} x=e^{\log Z_{\beta-u/N} -\log Z_\beta}$$
Then
$$\Bbb E_\beta[f(X)^k] = \frac{\text{d}^k}{\text{d}u^k}\Psi(u)
=e^{-\log Z_\beta}\frac{\text{d}^k}{\text{d}u^k} e^{\log Z_{\beta-u/N}}$$
Obviously, this does not answer the question, but I do not believe there is a generic formula for the moments of $X$ itself since this depends on the choice of the representation of $X$.

Comment: Notice though that I'm not looking for the expectation of f(X) but rather that of X

Comment: I'm afraid so. I also wonder what these moment genereting formula are useful for, in the end they will just be a way to write out the definition of the moment $\sum_x  g(x) \frac{e^{-\beta f(x)}}{Z_{\beta}}$ where do they ever come in handy?